# How to add data to the list when "pull to refresh" without clearing old data

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, pull-to-refresh

I have a PulltoRefreshListView control:

```
 public class PullToRefreshListView : ListView
    {
        private const string ScrollViewerControl = "ScrollViewer";
        private const string ContainerGrid = "ContainerGrid";
        private const string PullToRefreshIndicator = "PullToRefreshIndicator";
        private const string RefreshButton = "RefreshButton";
        private const string VisualStateNormal = "Normal";
        private const string VisualStateReadyToRefresh = "ReadyToRefresh";

        private DispatcherTimer compressionTimer;
        private ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
        private DispatcherTimer timer;
        private Grid containerGrid;
        private Border pullToRefreshIndicator;
        private bool isCompressionTimerRunning;
        private bool isReadyToRefresh;
        private bool isCompressedEnough;

        public event EventHandler RefreshContent;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PullTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PullText", typeof(string), typeof(PullToRefreshListView), new PropertyMetadata("Pull to refresh"));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RefreshTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RefreshText", typeof(string), typeof(PullToRefreshListView), new PropertyMetadata("Release to refresh"));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RefreshHeaderHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RefreshHeaderHeight", typeof(double), typeof(PullToRefreshListView), new PropertyMetadata(40D));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RefreshCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RefreshCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(PullToRefreshListView), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ArrowColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ArrowColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(PullToRefreshListView), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));

        private double offsetTreshhold = 40;
        public PullToRefreshListView()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(PullToRefreshListView);
            Loaded += PullToRefreshScrollViewer_Loaded;
            this.SizeChanged += PullToRefreshListView_SizeChanged;
        }

        private void PullToRefreshListView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ItemsPanelRoot != null)
                ItemsPanelRoot.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        }

        public ICommand RefreshCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RefreshCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RefreshCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public double RefreshHeaderHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(RefreshHeaderHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RefreshHeaderHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public string RefreshText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(RefreshTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RefreshTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public string PullText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PullTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PullTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush ArrowColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ArrowColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ArrowColorProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnApplyTemplate();
                scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)GetTemplateChild(ScrollViewerControl);
                scrollViewer.ViewChanging += ScrollViewer_ViewChanging;
                scrollViewer.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, -RefreshHeaderHeight);
                var transform = new CompositeTransform();
                transform.TranslateY = -RefreshHeaderHeight;
                scrollViewer.RenderTransform = transform;

                containerGrid = (Grid)GetTemplateChild(ContainerGrid);
                pullToRefreshIndicator = (Border)GetTemplateChild(PullToRefreshIndicator);
                SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
            }
            catch (Exception wd)
            {
                var dwd = wd.Message;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initiate timers to detect if we're scrolling into negative space
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void PullToRefreshScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show Refresh Button on non-touch device.
            if (new Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities().TouchPresent == 0)
            {
                var refreshButton = (Button)GetTemplateChild(RefreshButton);
                refreshButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                refreshButton.Click += RefreshButton_Click;
            }

            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

            compressionTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            compressionTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5);
            compressionTimer.Tick += CompressionTimer_Tick;

            timer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clip the bounds of the control to avoid showing the pull to refresh text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Clip = new RectangleGeometry()
            {
                Rect = new Rect(0, 0, e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height)
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Detect if we've scrolled all the way to the top. Stop timers when we're not completely in the top
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NextView.VerticalOffset == 0)
            {
                timer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                if (timer != null)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                }

                if (compressionTimer != null)
                {
                    compressionTimer.Stop();
                }

                isCompressionTimerRunning = false;
                isCompressedEnough = false;
                isReadyToRefresh = false;

                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, VisualStateNormal, true);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Detect if I've scrolled far enough and been there for enough time to refresh
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void CompressionTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (isCompressedEnough)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, VisualStateReadyToRefresh, true);
                isReadyToRefresh = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isCompressedEnough = false;
                compressionTimer.Stop();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke timer if we've scrolled far enough up into negative space. If we get back to offset 0 the refresh command and event is invoked. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (containerGrid != null)
            {
                Rect elementBounds = pullToRefreshIndicator.TransformToVisual(containerGrid).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, pullToRefreshIndicator.Height, RefreshHeaderHeight));
                var compressionOffset = elementBounds.Bottom;

                if (compressionOffset > offsetTreshhold)
                {
                    if (isCompressionTimerRunning == false)
                    {
                        isCompressionTimerRunning = true;
                        compressionTimer.Start();
                    }

                    isCompressedEnough = true;
                }
                else if (compressionOffset == 0 && isReadyToRefresh == true)
                {
                    InvokeRefresh();
                }
                else
                {
                    isCompressedEnough = false;
                    isCompressionTimerRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, object e)
        {
            InvokeRefresh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set correct visual state and invoke refresh event and command
        /// </summary>
        private void InvokeRefresh()
        {
            isReadyToRefresh = false;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, VisualStateNormal, true);

            if (RefreshContent != null)
            {
                RefreshContent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

            if (RefreshCommand != null && RefreshCommand.CanExecute(null) == true)
            {
                RefreshCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

and i use it in xaml:

```
<controls:PullToRefreshListView ItemsSource="{Binding TrackListItems}"
   RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
</controls:PullToRefreshListView>
```

and code behind:

```
refreshCommand = new RelayCommandN(RefreshItems);
public void RefreshItems()
{
 TrackListItems.Clear();
//code: added my data in List: TrackListItems
}
```

In this way I always have new data, but the sheet is cleaned completely. How to do to the old data remain, and only add new data to the top of the list after "Pull To Refresh"?
What is the right strategy? I can find the data are marked as new. How to add them to the top of the list? And that there is no glitches? And do not clear the all list?

Comment: Why can't you just add the new data to the list? If it's an ObservableCollection the changes will show in the UI.

Comment: How to add data to the top of the list? I need like a Facebook application for windows phone, when you do "pulltorefresh".  In top of the list added last news? and update old post, without clear list.

Comment: `list.Insert(0, item);` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If the new data, more than one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List.Insert(0, newItem)` to add items to the top of the list. If you want to add multiple items, you'll call have to use it multiple times. Note that calling Insert with 0 adds the items to the top of the list, which works if your items are in reverse order. If you want to add them in order, you can do something like this:

```
public void Refresh(ObservableCollection<Item> myList, List<Item> newItems)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < newItems.Count; i++)
    {
        myList.Insert(i, newItem=newItems[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried. The addition takes place in the top sheet. But not as much as I wanted. There is a flicker as if a sheet is cleaned and re-filled. How to prevent the update of the screen? To add was smoothly?

Comment: @arsenium Do you have to clear the list? It should work fine if you just insert the items without clearing it.